# How can we create sums of a View's table column values in a header and/or footer?

Tags: views

We have a View with multiple decimal field value rows. We need to create a sum (add all of the values) for these columns in a header and/or footer of the View. I see there is a D7 module called [Views Calc](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_calc) that looks like it may do what we need but there is no work on a D8/9 port.

How can we accomplish this in D9?

[image]